# Could not write JSON: Could not set field value [t] by reflection

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

I'm working on a Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE project. 
I have a field in an Oracle database declared as `CHAR(1)` with a JPA converter as follows:

```
public class CharToBooleanConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean convertToDatabaseColumn(String s) {
        return s.equalsIgnoreCase("t");
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(Boolean aBoolean) {

        if(aBoolean.equals(true)){
            return "t";
        } else {
            return "f";
        }
    }
}
```

This converter is used in my `StructureElement` class twice:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OBS_STRUCTURE_ELEMENT2")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "structure_element_seq", sequenceName = "structure_element_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class StructureElement {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NO_ELEMENT")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "structure_element_seq")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "TAG")
    private String tag;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "SUITE")
    private int sequence;

    @Column(name = "OPTIONNEL")
    @Convert(converter = CharToBooleanConverter.class)
    private boolean optional;

    @Column(name = "REPETITIF")
    @Convert(converter = CharToBooleanConverter.class)
    private boolean repetitive;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "NOM_STRUCTURE_TYPE")
    private Structure typeStructure;

    @Embedded
    private PersistenceSignature signature;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to send a `Structure` through a RestController I receive the following  in console:

> Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Could not set field value [t] value by reflection : [class be.solodoukhin.domain.StructureElement.optional] setter of be.solodoukhin.domain.StructureElement.optional; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not set field value [t] value by reflection : [class be.solodoukhin.domain.StructureElement.optional] setter of be.solodoukhin.domain.StructureElement.optional (through reference chain: be.solodoukhin.domain.Structure["elements"])]

With an `500 Internal Server Error` response.

Here is my method:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/structure")
public class StructuresController {
    @GetMapping("/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<Structure> getOne(@PathVariable("name") String name)
    {
        LOGGER.info("Call to StructuresController.getOne with name = " + name);
        Optional<Structure> found = this.structureRepository.findById(name);
        if(found.isPresent()){
            return ResponseEntity.ok(found.get());
        }
        else
        {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to use hibernate specific annotation `@Type(type = "true_false")`. It works but this produces an uppercase `T` or `F` in the database.

I've tried to write a JSON serializer that extends `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer` using this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations) without success.

Comment: unrelated to the problem, but `if(aBoolean.equals(true))` is redundant. `if (aBoolean)` would be sufficient already (since a boolean validates to true/false already)

Comment: Also is there a reason why the T and F can't be uppercase in your database?

Comment: @Codeer I can go for uppercase values but I would like to know if there is a solution without touching the database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't your converter the wrong way round? Your `convertToDatabaseColumn` has it going from a String to a Boolean. Surely you want it going from Boolean to String. And the `convertToEntityAttribute` going from String to Boolean.

I suspect that the convert is returning a value of "t" or "f" which can't then be put into the boolean field in the entity.

I think it should be...

```
public class CharToBooleanConverter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, String> {
    @Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
        return s != null && s.equalsIgnoreCase("t");
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean aBoolean) {
        return (aBoolean != null && aBoolean) ? "t" : "f";
    }
}
```